# problem with calling libraries

Tags: c++, libraries

hi 
i'm watching a c++ tutorial and
instructor includes the libraries like this

```
# include  "map.h"
#include "set.h"
```

but when i use this code i get error

> fatal error C1083: Cannot open include
>   file: 'set.h': No such file or
>   directory

so i have to write it like this

```
# include  <map>
#include <set>
```

but now i have another problem 
when i create an set or map ob , the methods that i can use are different from what is shown in the tutorial 
for example in the tutorial instructor create and navigate a set or map like this

```
set<int> ss;
set<int>::itrator itr = ss.itrator();
while(itr.hasnext()){

cout<<itr.next();
}
```

but my ss and object doesn't have this methods

```
ss.itrator();
itr.hasnext()
itr.next();
```

an i have to write this code like this

```
set<int> ss;
set<int>::itrator itr = ss.begin();
while(!itr.end()){

cout<<*itr;
}
```

what is the problem ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pretty obviously, your tutorial doesn't use the Standard Template Library, and uses a custom library of its own. `#include "set.h"` looks for a `set.h` file in the user search path, which is usually the current directory. Since you don't have the file, the compiler emits an error.

When you `#include <set>`, you get the STL `set` class. Your tutorial's `"set.h"` file probably would probably give you another class (same goes for `<map>` and `"map.h"`).

Anyhow, if you're following a C++ tutorial, you might as well try to find one about the STL, since it's got wider support and adoption that most other C++ libraries. You can [follow one here](http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/LinuxTutorialC++STL.html).

The corresponding code for your snippet would probably be the following:

```
set<int> ss;
for (set<int>::iterator itr = ss.begin(); itr != ss.end(); itr++)
{
    cout << *itr;
}
```

Instead of `ss.iterator()`, you have `ss.begin()`, which returns an iterator positioned to the "beginning" of your set. Instead of `itr.hasnext()`, you must compare `itr` to `ss.end()`; `ss.end()` returns an iterator positioned to the "end" of the set, so you know you're not done iterating while your iterator is not the same as an iterator positioned to the end of the collection. `itr++` and `*itr` take place of `itr.next()`.

In your context, `itr.next()` both returns the current element and advances the iterator by one. This is bad design because the object provides no means to just access the current element, leading to duplicate code if you just want to access the current element multiple times. The STL iterators have distinct operations for advancing and obtaining the referenced element: `itr++` advances the iterator, and `*itr` obtains the current element.

Comment: Nitpick: `for ( std::<int>::` **const_**`iterator itr = ss.begin(),` **end = ss.end()**`; itr != end ;` **++**`itr)`.

Comment: @mmutz I'm voluntarily leaving `const` iterators out of my answer for the sake of simplicity. For the rest, I admit I have never done something like `end = ss.end()` in the premise of a `for` loop (`collection.end()` never showed up in a profiling report of any of my programs).

Comment: [nitpick (1)](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/nitpick) :) Regarding the `end = ss.end()`: it's called "avoiding premature pessimisation".

Answer (score 1):

Most probably it's a typo:

```
set<int>::iterator itr = ss.iterator();
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's `ss.begin()`. In which case it's kinda more than a typo.

Comment: Who downvoted and why? @zneak , that doesn't mean my answer is wrong. I answered the the user problem, which was `my ss and object doesn't have this methods`.

Comment: You're right that `std::set` doesn't have an `itrator` method, but it doesn't have an `iterator` method either. The `std::set<T>::iterator` member is a typedef, and types aren't callable. It does, however, have a `begin` method. (Still, I'm not the downvoter.)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're using a Java tutorial to learn how to use C++ iterators. The approach like this is correct:

```
set<int> ss;
set<int>::iterator iter = ss.begin();

while (iter != ss.end()){
  cout << *iter <<endl;
  iter++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include "set.h"
```

This looks for a file named `set.h` in the same directory as the file including it. It's telling you that doesn't exist. You need to create it / move it there.

```
#include <set>
```

That's searching your include path and finding the STL `set` which of course does not have the methods you've defined for your class in your own `set.h`