# set class ignoring defined comp fn and errors on default comparison

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, set

I am using a custom Set class that is basically the same as the STL Set class

The problem is that I am somehow implementing it incorrectly and the default comparison function is used rather than a comparison I defined.

```
Set<Lexicon::CorrectionT> Lexicon::suggestCorrections(Lexicon::MatchesT & matchSet)
{
    Set<CorrectionT> suggest(compareCorr); //ordered Set
    suggestCorrectionsHelper(root, suggest, 0, matchSet.testWord, 0, matchSet.testTime);
    return suggest;
}


int compareCorr(Lexicon::CorrectionT a, Lexicon::CorrectionT b)
{
    if (a.editDistance < b.editDistance)
        return -1;
    else if (a.editDistance == b.editDistance)
            return 0;
    else
        return 1;
}

struct CorrectionT {
    int editDistance; //stackItems
    string suggestedWord; //stackItems
};
```

Some research:

- [The class library](http://www.stanford.edu/class/cs106x/cs106lib/class_set.html)
- An issue with [the same class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5843594/problem-with-calling-libraries) - suggested that the STL Set class is used, in this case I might still need help understanding how to define the comparison function, so posting question

I have 19 C2784 errors all relating to some form of "error C2784: 'bool std::operator ==(const std::_Tree<_Traits> &,const std::_Tree<_Traits> &)' : could not deduce template argument for 'const std::_Tree<_Traits> &' from 'Lexicon::CorrectionT'

and referencing this code

```
template <typename Type>
int OperatorCmp(Type one, Type two) {
    if (one == two) return 0;
    if (one < two) return -1;
    return 1;
}
```

My question: how do you suggest correcting this?

Attempt at changing default definition type:

```
#include "lexicon.h"

//template <typename Type>
int OperatorCmp(Lexicon::CorrectionT one, Lexicon::CorrectionT two) {
    if (one.editDistance == two.editDistance) return 0;
    if (one.editDistance < two.editDistance) return -1;
    return 1;
}

#endif
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comparison function for STL `set` must be a [Strict Weak Ordering](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/StrictWeakOrdering.html), so that class is **not** the same as an STL `set`.

The error indicates the default `OperatorCmp` is being used, I don't know why, but you could make that default one work by defining `operator<` and `operator==` for your `CorrectionT` type.

Comment: I tried that and it caused errors in the set class - I will try it again

Comment: Is it not Strict Weak Ordering only because there is the possibility that a == b?

Comment: 1) can I use the STL set ? And, I tried changing the default compare function definition to CorrectionT. But, #include "lexicon.h"

//template <typename Type>
int OperatorCmp(Lexicon::CorrectionT one, Lexicon::CorrectionT two) {
 if (one.editDistance == two.editDistance) return 0;
 if (one.editDistance < two.editDistance) return -1;
 return 1;
}

#endif

Comment: 1) can I use the STL set ? And, I tried changing the default compare function definition to CorrectionT. There are errors that I cannot resolve: C2653: 'Lexicon' : is not a class or namespace name, C2065: 'CorrectionT' : undeclared identifier, C2146: syntax error : missing ')' before identifier 'one'

Comment: A strict weak ordering returns true or false, not -1, 0 or +1, it's very different.  You could use `std::set` if you define a less-than comparison for your type. The other errors are not related, you'll just have to learn how to interpret the errors and fix them yourself.